How to print something only once at the end of a recursive function
I have a simple study function:
#include<stdio.h>

void func1(int i){
    
    if(i == 6) return; // Base Case
    printf("%d ", i);
    func1(i + 1);
    printf("\nEnd1");
}

int main()
{
    func1(1); // *
    return 0;
}



The func1() has *no input.

I continue to receive:
this output (!!!?):
1 2 3 4 5
End1
End1
End1
End1
End1

no errors in Terminal


$ cd "/e/Prog_Lang/Module/" && gcc recur_pnt1_5.c -o recur_pnt1_5.exe && "/e/to Prog_Lang/Module/"recur_pnt1_5.exe <input.txt> output.txt
e5-4bdc-b5e2-716617ce55ca
XXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXXXX MINGW64 /e/Prog_Lang/Module 17 (main)


Expected output:
1 2 3 4 5
End1

I don't know what I can try to solve.
Any ideas?

Each invocation of func1 that prints a number will also print \nEnd1. Why do you expect that to only be printed once?

As an option you could print the "End1" output in the base case.

is a recursion, func1(i + 1); is Jumped over when:
"if(i == 6) return; // Base Case"     is    true
then should be to be printed "End1" and the func1 ends.

@Ken White prinf("End"); is required to be in the function by the Problem, then initially I havent received this error (1 End1 only as expected) but now I only receive this output. - Thanks all for help fron now!

@Some programmer dude I think is the same but I try...

Use the debugger to step through the code to trace the execution path. The debugger is the best tool you have available to you to find logic errors. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to start learning. There are many uses for it while coding, and this is a perfect example of one of them.

@Some programmer dude: this solve it but is Wrong Answer cause prinf("End"); is asked to be "after" the recursive call.

@Ken White What is the best way to have a tracing "MS-Dos - Trace on" like?

What does this have to do with MS-Dos? Use the debugger that is available for your programming language or IDE.

@Ken White I activate Vs Code degugger but I haven't received steps of code line by line (only normal output) I got extensive information about compilation, shortly no line numbers

@greg spear anyway I voted answer for the "Runnable code is here"  link on godbolt online compiler that is very usefull.

@Ken White I see u too young...
anyway is for explane the kind of tracing I have in mind: to view every step to every output. In dos, enabling trace (cmd "trace on" [need genuine dos 2.0 or above] I have to look but I think that now in Windows cmd is not present cause, probably, was related to autoexec.bat and cfg.sys) is printed on screen every line of baches executed. (but I think that to run dos is necessary at least a DosBox, or use MS Hyper-V/WM Ware [should be necessary a plug-ins or settings also in both solution]. |or ☄ is a Energy Bolt (UOtm) or "Fireball" I have to catch?|

The base case is when the recursion is done. As is when the original call in main returns. Those are really your only two options.

if you use VS Code then you definitely don't use MS-DOS. The command prompt (cmd) is very different and powershell is another beast that has nothing to do with DOS

@everyone drop some parameter and tools and info to have a good tracing!!

@pvt-Tron: I see u too young. Guess again, youngster. I've been writing code for getting close to half a century, and started out with GW-Basic and assembly, where my only debugger was the debug command at a DOS prompt. But MS-DOS has been dead since Win95 days, so it doesn't exist any longer. Every development environment now has built-in development support or a good debugger available (such as gdb), all of which are much more powerful than debug with or without trace on. So again, what does your question have to do with MS-DOS?

@Ken White: 'Ubi Major Minor Cessat', but: I'm not totally a 'noob' in ex. I'was first in Apple//e course on Basic, 40 years ago... but had to wait 6 years to put my hands on 4dos and E3... on a dx2-33, it seams to me You typified trace on...

@everyone: So, can anyone spare a hint about where look for the kinda tacing i need?

@Ken White: from dos 5.0 was active multi boot cfg... an trace on was essential... then in 6.0 there was, If I remember well, also a user option.

And you're still prattling on about DOS, which is totally irrelevant. USE THE DEBUGGER that is provided with your compiler or development environment. It will let you step through the code line by line, evaluate variables, and most of them will even allow you to look at the assembly code that was generated. Stop obsessing about the deceased DOS and listen to what people are telling you.

I copied the entire code and executed it with the result of
1 2 3 4 5 
End1
End1
End1
End1
End1

In your function fun1, there is a statement printf("\nEnd1"); and the recursion end when i == 6. So each time the fun1 was called in the recursion, \nEnd1 would be printed to the terminal.
If you only want to print it at the end of the recursion, you should change your fun1 like this
void func1(int i){
    
    if(i == 6) 
    {
        printf("\nEnd1");
        return ;
    } 
    printf("%d ", i);
    func1(i + 1);
}


thanks for try but as I wrote above to @Ken White prinf("End"); is required to be in the function by the Problem, then initially I havent received this error (1 End1 only as expected) but now I only receive this output. - Thanks all for help fron now!

You did not get the output you expected because the logic the code used did not support that output.  Please note the small change in the logic of func1() -- braces are placed around the code block of the condition (i==6).  This code block now includes the End1 statement so the program can give output as expected.
UPDATE:  as specified per your requirement, the printf(End1) statement is now placed after the recursive call.
Runnable code is here.
#include<stdio.h>

void func1(int i)
{
    if(i < 6) 
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
        func1(i + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("End1\n");
    }
}    

int main()
{
    func1(1);
    return 0;
}

Output:
    1 2 3 4 5 End1


thanks for try but as I wrote above to @Ken White prinf("End"); is required to be in the function by the Problem, then initially I havent received this error (1 End1 only as expected) but now I only receive this output. - Thanks all for help fron now!

@pvt-Tron -- Thank you for your kind feedback.  The code is now updated per the requirement.

Think I won't get a leat one ✔ but Is a almost a possible solution.
it run with no errors -> follow the link to verify code ( it opens a web page) ↗ here

@pvt-Tron -- thx for selecting my answer and thx for the fun challenge.

@everyone but according to me the code after func() called by itself is executed after the flow encounter a return... Isn't it?

@everyone if after func1(i + 1); I return i; (changing void to int above) I will have multiple executions?

well, I though also this one and the printing of "End1" is after recursion call, in gives only one output:
#include<stdio.h>

int cntg1 = 1;
int fend1(){
    if(cntg1 < 2){
        printf("\nEnd1");
        cntg1++;
    }
    return 0;
}
void func1(int i){
    
    if(i == 6) return; // Base Case
    printf("%d ", i);
    func1(i + 1);
    fend1(); // <<< this is factory new
}


int main()
{
    func1(1); // *
    return 0;
}

The following link open a new website page click here↗ to view the code run.
There is a similar solution that avoid the use a Global variable?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Community ok but you sentry
